# How do I give the user the ability to choose the location and name of an excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, export, export-to-excel

All I have been able to use so far is

the .SaveAs(path) method but the use user to be able to choose their path.

Comment: What kind of application are you making? WinForms has a SaveFileDialog.

Comment: An application for calculating tax liability, which gives the user the ability to download and save an excel file. I'm using C# and XAML. any tips ?

Comment: By XAML do you mean WPF?

Comment: All solved guys, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

I've made the following method a while back:

```cs
private bool SaveFileDialog(string fileName, string ext, string filter, string title, object file)
{
    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog()
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        DefaultExt = ext,
        Filter = filter,
        Title = title
    };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        return false;

    string path = dialog.FileName;

    //here save the file, e.g. File.WriteAllText(path, file.ToString()); for a string

    return true;
}
```

Parameters:

- **fileName** Default name for the file
- **defaultExt** Extension of the file, e.g. ".xlsx"
- **filter**  What types could be save, e.g. "Excel File (.xlsx) |* .xlsx"
- **title** The title of the DialogBox

As I don't know what type you're working with I just placed an `object file` as a parameter. Replace this with your type and then you can save the file to the selected path at the end (see comment).

If the user selected any file and the file was saved, the method returns true, otherwise, it returns false or throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you, adapted your code to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Save File Dialog to give a user the option where to save the data, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0

```
using (var dlg = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    //add more if you like
    //check the example on MSDN
    dlg.Filter = "xls files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        YourObject.SaveAs(dlg.FileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adapted your code to solve the problem

Comment: This is the better answer because you are using a `using` which I don't have in my method. +1